# React/Redux/Reselect - mapStateToProps stops firing even after seeing changes reflected in the reducer.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I searched for a similar issue but couldn't find an appropriate post (...although I have a suspicion this question has been asked before) so my apologies in advance.

I've been using Redux with React for a couple of projects now and just started including immutable.js and Reselect in a learning project.  My testing/learning project just loads a large JSON object into state and then I use Reselect to grab portions of it to then pass into my component.  Here's an example of the object I'm loading:

```
export const formState = {
  progress: {
    groupId: 3,
    questionId: 5,
  },
  content: [
    {
      group: { id: 1, name: 'Company', description: 'Data regarding your company.', questions: 2 },
      questions: [
        {
          id: 1,
          type: 'textField',
          label: 'Required *',
          inputLabelProps: { shrink: true },
          text: 'group 1 question 1',
          answer: '',
        },
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ]
  }
```

This object is loaded into state via an action triggered in componentWillMount()  which then flows through the reducer eventually triggering mapStateToProps within the component that looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
   console.log(state);
   return {
     progress: getProgressData(state),
     content: getContentData(state),
   };
 };
```

This works as expected.  The component has two buttons that let you traverse the questions array found in the content object of the above "overall state."

Additionally, when you press the forward or backwards button to traverse the questions array noted above, the progress object gets updated via an action that then gets updated within the reducer via:

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PROGRESS:
      formState = state.get('formState');
      formState.progress = action.payload;
      console.log(formState);
      return state
        .set('formState', formState);
```

So this is where it gets weird.  The first time I click forwards or backwards it works and I see the object get updated and the next question is shown in my component.  As expected....

If I click back or next again I see the action get fired, I see the appropriate state reflected in the reducer but I will not longer see state in the console.log in mapStateToProps.  It never gets to that point.  Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

**Note**: It may seem weird that I'm not just updating state in the reducer via: 
    return state
        .setIn(['formState', 'progress'], formState)

I tried doing that initially but was getting an invalid key path.  This is pretty strange to me considering I'm converting the initial state into an immutable.js map via fromJS() so I thought anything contained within would be a map or a list or whatever is appropriate and therefore addressable in this way... regardless, I figured I'd fix that once I fixed the above issue.  That is, unless they are related.

As always, any help is appreciated and sincere apologies if this is a duplicate question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

Immutable.js function Collection.get returns the value behind the given key, which in this case is a pointer to an object. Currently, you change that object, then set it back with Collection.set. The object changed, but the pointer to that object which is the value stored in your state did not. Therefore your state is technically unchanged and your component does not update.

This problem occurs because you are storing a plain object inside an Immutable.js Collection. You should either use only plain objects or play it safe with only Immutable.js Collections. Don't mix them.

### Fix

#### Option 1: Immutable.js Collections

Make state.formState an Immutable.js Collection as well. Then change it via Immutable.js methods.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PROGRESS: {
      let formState = state.get('formState');
      formState = formState.set('progress', action.payload)
      console.log(formState);
      return state
        .set('formState', formState);
    }
```

If you decide to use Immutable.js you should make sure not to leave in any vanilla javascript objects, because they can circumvent the protections afforded by Immutable.js.

#### Option 2: plain objects (recommended)

Make state a vanilla javascript object.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PROGRESS: {
      const formState = { ...state.formState };
      formState.progress = action.payload
      console.log(formState);
      return { ...state, formState };
    }
```

If you decide not to use Immutable.js you will have to be careful not to accidentally change the state directly. Easiest way to do that is to copy the state using the spread syntax: `const stateCopy = { ...state };`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'll be digging into this suggestion soon.

Comment: I find my issue was when I was first setting the large object in state I wasn't performing fromJS which made things weird as the initial state had that but subsequent versions didn't.  After fixing that I was then able to make use of .setIn and it was all good.  

Thanks for the feedback.  Selecting your answer as the most helpful as it started me down the right path to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't update state in reducer. It almost always will result in weir behavior, [immutable-update-patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns). Did you try returning new object? i.e.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PROGRESS:
      return {
         ...state,
         formState: {
           ...state.formState,
           progress: action.payload
         }
      };
```

Comment: I will give that a try.  Ultimately after thinking about it, I may have to figure out my overall state issue with why I can't simple use .setIn.  Using immutable and not doing so seems like everything I will do as a work around will be some sort of anti-pattern.

Comment: I find my issue was when I was first setting the large object in state I wasn't performing fromJS which made things weird as the initial state had that but subsequent versions didn't.  After fixing that I was then able to make use of .setIn and it was all good.  

Thanks for the feedback.